# cygwin doesnt recognize >> operator? C++

Tags: c++, cygwin, compiler-errors, cin

cout and the << operator work fine in compiling c++ program in CYgwin but as soon as i try the cin >> operator, compiler breaks says cygwin doesnt recognize >>? wt is that about?
source code:

```
#include "TenStrings.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using std::cin;

//Default Constructor
TenStrings::TenStrings()
{
    int ithElement; 


    strings[0] = "String 1";
    strings[1] = "String 2";
    strings[2] = "String 3";
    strings[3] = "String 4";
    strings[4] = "String 5";
    strings[5] = "String 6";
    strings[6] = "String 7";
    strings[7] = "String 8";
    strings[8] = "String 9";
    strings[9] = "String 10";

    cout << "Enter how many strings you would like to alter: " << endl;
    int numAlter;
    cin >> numAlter >> endl;
    //cin >> "Enter which string to change: " << ithElement << endl;

    cout << strings[0] << endl; 
    cout << strings[3] << endl;
}
```

Comment: Can we see the source code that is causing problems? It's possible that there's something else going on, and it would help to be able to see exactly how you're using the operator.

Comment: Could you please provide the exact text of the error message and some sample code which causes it. Seriously, there's plenty of room in the text box and you aren't going to run out of letters.

Comment: Sample code? What exact compiler are you using? What error are you getting?

Comment: A sample code will help people answer if that's your fault or cygwin's.

Comment: thats really all to the program.. cout works fine

Comment: @user593301: Thanks for posting the source code, couldn't see the problem without it.  Next time it would also be good to paste the error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, now we see the problem.  You shouldn't use `endl` with `cin`.

Say just `cin >> numAlter;` and it will automatically wait for the enter key to be pressed.

You don't need both `using namespace std;` and `using std::cin;`.  That was just a wild guess because I couldn't be sure of your problem without seeing the code.

<strike>My crystal ball says your program starts with:</strike>

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
```

Add the following line:

```
using std::cin;
```

and then you will be able to use `cin` without writing the qualified name (`std::cin`).

Comment: @user593301: Don't worry, I've probably done more dumb things while programming than you have.